# WSO2 IS Federated Authenticator claim

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How can I send the federated authenticator as a claim to my service provider ?

The SP wants to know which one has been used to authenticate the subject. Is there a local IS claim to send back to the SP ?

I already know about *Always send back the authenticated list of identity providers* but I need a claim to send.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom claim handler that handles the claim mapping and deploy it into IS server. You can follow this document and create a custom claim handler https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Writing+a+Custom+Claim+Handler. You can get the federatedIdpName from the AuthneticatedUser object [1].

A sample code is given below.

```
public Map<String, String> handleClaimMappings(StepConfig stepConfig,
                                               AuthenticationContext context, Map<String, String> remoteAttributes,
                                               boolean isFederatedClaims) throws FrameworkException {

    String authenticatedUser = null;

    if (stepConfig != null) {
        //calling from StepBasedSequenceHandler
        authenticatedUser = stepConfig.getAuthenticatedUser();
    } else {
        //calling from RequestPathBasedSequenceHandler
        authenticatedUser = context.getSequenceConfig().getAuthenticatedUser();
    }

    Map<String, String> claims = handleExternalClaims(authenticatedUser);
    return claims;
}

private Map<String, String> handleExternalClaims(AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser) throws FrameworkException {

    Map<String, String> externalClaims = new HashMap<String, String>();
    externalClaims.put("http://test.org/claims/idpName", authenticatedUser.getFederatedIdPName());
    return externalClaims;
}
```

[1]https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/blob/master/components/authentication-framework/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authentication/framework/model/AuthenticatedUser.java#L49